# Joomla: Add pagination to edit-view

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, joomla3.3

I would like to add a pagination to the edit-view of my component in the backend.

There are 2 views:

- emails
- email

The pagination is working in the view "emails" but not in the view "email". The view "emails" shows different conversations, the view "email" shows the emails, which are linked to the conversation.

If there are more than 10 mails I would like to add the pagination, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

In your view.html.php add something like:

```
$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

This creates a pagination object and assigns it to the view so it's then available in the template. This also assumes that your model extends JModelList which has the getPagination method.

Then in your template file you can do:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

and that should output your pagination.

Works for me! ;-)

Comment: Hi, this works only if I use JModelList, but in this case I have to use JModelAdmin, because I need getItem() as override, which does not exist in JModelList.

I tried this, and it shows a pagination, but if you click on a link you are getting redirected to the standard-view, which is defined in the controller.

This is the tutorial I tried: http://www.tutsforu.com/pagination-in-joomla-component.html

Comment: But if you're overriding getItem I assume that's because you're returning more than one row? Otherwise you wouldn't need the pagination, right? So why not extend JModelList and override getListQuery with the code from getItem? I do this in my component and it works okay.

Comment: Hi Adam, well, the problem is, that my model fetches data from different database-tables. That's my code so far: http://d.pr/n/5Wpl

I don't know if that is possible with JModelList and getListQuery...

Comment: You're taking an item and appending new properties to it (metadata and messages). But you're still only getting back one item from getItem and you can't paginate one item! What you need to do is extend JModelList and write a new getListQuery method. The difference being that the getListQuery method would contain the SQL to pull out the records you're interested in. It would contain the SQL you've written already (referencing the __bestia_mails_messages table) and joining other tables where necessary (e.g. the one referenced by the original parent::getItem() call. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Hi Adam,

so your suggestion, just to make sure that I understand you correctly, is to extend getListQuery and left join the items in the second table, right?

The pagination is the thing: The pagination should just handle the items from the 2nd database, the mails.

Comment: Yes. Just change your model to extend from JModelList and then override the getListQuery method with the necessary SQL. Then in your view.html.php change $this->item = $this->get('Item') to $this->items = $this->get('Items'). You may need to tweak a few other bits here and there for routing and filtering but it definitely works as I've done it myself ;-)

Comment: Hi Adam,

I tried it out yesterday. But I need the checkout()-function and permissions, which, as soon as I got now, are provided by JModelAdmin :-(

Comment: Without seeing more of the code and the screens you're working on it difficult to know how to resolve. How many views are you dealing with, 2 or 3? Permissions and checkout can probably be taken care of in the controller, no?

Comment: Hi Adam,

I just had an idea, maybe you can tell me, if this is a possibility: Why not using more than 1 model? I can add another model in the controller.

1 representing the conversation
1 representing the mails

The conversation-model uses JModelAdmin, the mails-model JModelList.

What do you think?

Comment: Yes, but I thought problem is that there might be more than one conversation? Otherwise why do you need pagination? Probably best if you open a new question with more detail, or edit your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57939/discussion-between-adam-rifat-and-user3755325).